# Internet connection went off during an apt upgrade

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade

I was connected by ssh to my server, running `aptitude upgrade`, and, during the process, my Internet connection was off.

After reconnecting, the aptitude upgrade command was still running:

```
$ ps aux | grep apt
root     15186  0.0  0.0  68996  2108 ?        S    14:09   0:00 sudo aptitude upgrade
root     15187  3.9  1.4 262328 119080 ?       Sl   14:09   0:17 aptitude upgrade
```

and dpkg process is in locked state. Probably, the command is waiting for a confirmation to install the upgrades (the usual Y/n question).

How can I recover the process control to finish the command cleanly? ("connect" again to the standard input of the process to press 'Y').

If there's no way to do it, how safe is to just make a force kill of the upgrade by PID?

*NOTE*: I'm aware of `reptyr` to bring any process to foreground, but since I don't have currently that package, this is not a solution because I cannot use `dpkg` or its derivates to install new packages because it is in blocked state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill`ing it is usually fine, and certainly so if it's just at the Y/n prompt and has not started actually installing packages. At worst you'll need to run `apt-get -f install` and/or `dpkg --configure -a` a couple times.

Answer (score 1):

You have First of all you have to configure the available packages `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then try to `sudo apt-get autoremove` dependencies it may ask you to fix packages first of all `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and then you can delete the incomplete downloaded packages by `sudo apt-get clean` and now you are ready to resume upgrade with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing` or `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing`.